# How to toggle between like and unlike on Ajax success?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, toggle

My code properly works to insert like or delete like from database. And upon refresh of the page, it will show properly. But, how can I get it to toggle upon clicking? I have searched and tried solutions online, but none worked.

Here's my code:

```
// PHP CODE TO SEE IF USER ALREADY LIKES VIDEO
<?php

    $query272 = "SELECT * FROM video_likes WHERE video_id = :video_id272 AND user_id = :user_id272";
    $stmt272 = $pdo->prepare($query272);
    $stmt272->bindValue(':video_id272',$id123);
    $stmt272->bindValue(':user_id272',$userID);
    $stmt272->execute();
    $count272 = $stmt272->rowCount();

    if($count272 > 0) { $you_like_this = 1; } else { $you_dont_like_this = 1; }

    if($you_dont_like_this == 1) {

?>
```

Ajax Code

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#insertLike').click(function () {
      var videoID271 = $('#id').val();
      var userID271 = $('#userID').val();
      console.log('starting ajax');
      $.ajax({
        url: "./insert-like.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { id: videoID271, userID: userID271 },
        success: function (data) {
          var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(dataParsed);
        }
      });

    });
  });

</script>
```

Like Button Form:

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:12px" id="like">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id123; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="userID" id="userID" value="<?php echo $userID; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="you_like_this" id="you_like_this" value="1" />
<button onclick="insertLike(this)" class="insertLike" id="insertLike" style="background:none;border:none;text-decoration:none; color:#DD4400;font-weight:bold">Like</button>
</div>

    <?php } else { ?>
```

Dislike Button Ajax:

```
    <script>
  $(function () {
    $('#deleteLike').click(function () {
      var unlikeVideoID272 = $('#unlikeVideoID').val();
      var unlikeUserID272 = $('#unlikeUserID').val();
      console.log('starting ajax');
      $.ajax({
        url: "./delete-like.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { unlikeVideoID: unlikeVideoID272, unlikeUserID: unlikeUserID272 },
        success: function (data) {
          var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(dataParsed);
        }
      });

    });
  });

</script>
```

Dislike Form:

```
        <div style="float:left;margin-right:12px" id="unlike">
        <input type="hidden" name="unlikeVideoID" id="unlikeVideoID" value="<?php echo $id123; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="unlikeUserID" id="unlikeUserID" value="<?php echo $userID; ?>" />
        <button onclick="deleteLike(this)" class="deleteLike" id="deleteLike" style="background:none; border:none; text-decoration:none; color:#DD4400; font-weight:bold">Unlike</button>
        </div>
```

PHP Close:

```
<?php   } ?>
```

EDIT (as requested):

```
Table users     Table likes     Table videos

user_id <------- user_id -------> user_id

                 likes

                 video_id ------> id
```

Not using dislikes. Instead, using like, and unlike (when you've already liked it, you can change your mind and unlike it). Unlike will simply remove like from the table.

Once again, the insert into database works fine. I simply need to change the word like to the word unlike after Ajax Success 200. Well, not just the word. The script as well. When like turns into unlike, clicking unlike should like the video again. As if someone is bipolar and keeps changing their mood / opinion. Think of Facebook's like button. You click it. It likes a post. You click it again, it unlikes the post. No page refreshes needed.

Comment: I started an answer, but there’s not enough to build on.  There’s a bunch of duplication that needs to be factored out:  you don’t need two scripts going to two urls to make a binary change. Just send something like videoId, userId, and vote. Vote can be like or dislike.  Your php script updates database and responds with json and JavaScript receives the reply and adjusts the page. That’s all there is to it. However, I don’t see evidence that you have successfully received json back from php (your php script doesn’t show any output), nor do I see anything in your ajax function to deal with it

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the only thing this script does is properly inserts record into the database. What I need help with is the reporting back to PHP part. Also, I tried using one script and in the single page I was using, I had an else statement. If like then insert into like else delete from like... not sure if that was the proper way, but that's how I did it. And it didn't work. So, I created the two scripts and it works for inserting into the database. But still not for reporting back to PHP (the part I need help with). I can understand PHP well, but not so much Ajax / JQuery.

Comment: “but not for reporting back to php”... do you mean reporting back to the browser?  The problem I’m running in to is 1) I don’t know the schema (how you’re saving the relationship of users, likes, and videos 2) I don’t know how you’re displaying videos with likes or dislikes. If you could add these to the question (not comments) I’ll see if we can go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1:  plan database

From your select query, I gather that there are 3 tables involved here:

```
Video        Video_Likes  User
video_id --> video_id
             user_id <--- user_id
```

- To find total number of likes for a video, one would `select count(user_id) from video_likes where video_id=?`
- To find if a user likes a video, we could simply `select * from video_likes where user_id=? and video_id=?`

However, that doesn't work if you actually have a dislike.  In that case, we need to add another field to `video_likes`:

```
Video        Video_Likes  User
video_id --> video_id
             user_id <--- user_id
             affinity
```

where affinity= 'Like' | 'Dislike'  (I prefer to use human-readable values rather than 'L' | 'D')

Now, the queries would be

- `select count(user_id) from video_likes where video_id=? and affinity=?` for count of likes or dislikes
- `select affinity from video_likes where user_id=? and video_id=?` to find out if a user likes or dislikes a video

> note: there should be a unique key over video_id and user_id; you can't have more than one status for each video/user combination

### Step 2: plan presentation

Adding a couple of basic fields:

```
Video        Video_Likes  User
video_id --> video_id
title        user_id <--- user_id
             affinity     name
```

Simplified script, omitting much of the PHP logic for now

**videos.php**

```
<?php

// assuming you already have a PDO object named $pdo...
$sql = "select video.video_id, video.title, likes.total_likes, dislikes.total_dislikes
        from Video
        left join (
            select video_id, count(video_id) total_likes
            from Video_Likes
            where affinity = :like -- 'Like'
            group by video_id
        ) likes on video.video_id = likes.video_id
        left join (
            select video_id, count(video_id) total_dislikes
            from Video_Likes
            where affinity = :dislike -- 'Dislike'
            group by video_id
        ) dislikes on video.video_id = likes.video_id
        order by video.title";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);    
$stmt->execute(['like'=>'Like','dislike'=>'Dislike']);

// This is the end of all the PHP logic.  
// Now, we will output the view.  No more PHP except iteration, variable substitution and minor conditionals
?>
<html>
  <head><title>Sample</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video List</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Video</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
      </tr>

      <?php foreach($stmt as $row): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= htmlentities($row['title']) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlentities($row['likes']) ?? 'No Votes' ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlentities($row['dislikes']) ?? 'No Votes' ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Step 3: plan javascript

Assuming JQuery is loaded in the page (not shown above), add ajax transport

As it stands, there are no hooks nor any way to transfer information to ajax.  Fix it by adding class and data attribute:

```
      <?php foreach($stmt as $row): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $row['title'] ?></td>
        <td class="video-like" data-video-id="<?= $row['video_id'] ?>">
          <?= $row['likes'] ?? 'No Votes' ?>
        </td>
        <td class="video-dislike" data-video-id="<?= $row['video_id'] ?>">
          <?= $row['dislikes'] ?? 'No Votes' ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, make a couple of listeners and an ajax function just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
  // assign this from php
  var user_id = "<?= $user_id ?>";

  // the document ready section is not strictly needed, but doesn't hurt...
  $( document ).ready() {

    $('.video-like').on('click', function() {
      var video_id = $(this).data('video-id'); // may be data('videoId')
      setAffinity(video_id, 'Like');
    });

    $('.video-dislike').on('click', function() {
      var video_id = $(this).data('video-id'); // may be data('videoId')
      setAffinity(video_id, 'Dislike');
    });

  // close document ready
  }

  function setAffinity(video_id, affinity) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "./videos.php",
      type: "post",
      data: { user_id: user_id, video_id: video_id, affinity: affinity },
      success: function (data) {
        if(data.status == 'success') {
          // do something
        } else {
          // do something else
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

### Step 4: PHP receives data from ajax and responds

Before the logic for getting the page data (`$sql = "select video.video_id, video.title, likes.total_likes, dislikes.total_dislikes ..."`), check for a POST submission.  This is putting REST transactions into place.

```
<?php
// assuming you have managed user login and saved user_id in session
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ?? false;

// if there is a POST submission, we know a change to data is being requested.
if($user_id && array_key_exists('video_id',$_POST)) {

  // we are returning JSON; there can be no output before this.  That's why this is the first order of business.
  header("Content-type:application/json");

  // early exit on data validation failure
  if( !is_numeric($_POST['video_id'] ) {
    print json_encode( ['status'=>'failed', 'message'=>'Invalid video selected'] );
    die;
  }
  $video_id = $_POST['video_id'];

  // early exit on data validation failure
  if( !in_array( ['Like','Dislike'], $_POST['affinity'] ) {
    print json_encode( ['status'=>'failed', 'message'=>'You must select Like or Dislike'] );
    die;
  }
  $affinity = $_POST['affinity'];


  $sql = "insert into video_likes (video_id, user_id, affinity) values(?,?,?)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $success = $stmt->execute( [$video_id, $user_id, $affinity] );

  // early exit on failure
  if(!$success) {
    print json_encode( ['status'=>'failed','message'=>'Your selection was not recorded'] );
    die;
  }

  // let's send back the new count of likes and dislikes

  $sql = "select count(user_id) total from video_likes where video_id=? and affinity=?";
  $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->execute([$video_id, 'Likes']);
  $likes = $stmt->fetchColumn();

  $stmt->execute([$video_id, 'Dislikes']);
  $dislikes = $stmt->fetchColumn();

  print json_encode( ['status'=>'success', 'likes'=>$likes, 'dislikes'=>$dislikes] );
  die;
}

// continue with the page presentation as above...
```

### Step 5: receive PHP response back in browser

Back in javascript function `setAffinity()`...

```
  function setAffinity(video_id, affinity) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "./videos.php",
      type: "post",
      data: { user_id: user_id, video_id: video_id, affinity: affinity },
      success: function (data) {
        if(data.status == 'success') {
          // you will receive back {data: 'success', likes: $likes, dislikes: $dislikes}
          // locate the affected row and update the values
          // you may have to create an id for each like and dislike if this doesn't work...
          $('.video-like[data-video-id="' +data.likes+ '"]').html(data.likes);
          $('.video-dislike[data-video-id="' +data.dislikes+ '"]').html(data.likes);
        } else {
          alert(data.message);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the very descriptive answer. I'll probably try this out in the morning. I pretty much have step one figured out. But I do have a question. What is the difference between `count(user_id)` and `$stmt->rowCount();`? I ask because although I know both methods, I prefer to use `$stmt->rowCount();`.

Comment: I don’t do anything in MySQL, but I have found row count to be unreliable. It only applies to rows changed in odbc and other drivers.   See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count

Comment: I'm not sure I would trust the person that wrote that. He mentions, "if you still need to know how many rows has been returned by some query (though I hardly can imagine a case)". Why would you never need to count the rows? If you need to know how many videos, or how many comments, etc., you would need to count the rows, but he says, "though I hardly can imagine a case"?

Comment: I think his big bugaboo is using rowcount as a boolean to see if there are any results.  That practice is indeed silly... But as for getting a count, the count(*) is *far* more efficient, especially if your query uses `select *` and has many fields and rows.    If you really needed a count, you could either get the `sizeof()` the array or simply display $i++ as you iterate through the loop.

Comment: Oh, and it just dawned on me-- the queries I used absolutely require count, because rowCount isn't available in that context ;)