# Cant get php echo response in ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I only get 1 has a response in a blank page, what am i doing wrong ? I followed a tutorial, but it seems ajax dosent get the php response ? Im new to ajax.
PHP DB file -

```php
<?php
session_start();
include('security.php');
require_once('conexao.php');

$marca = $_POST['marca'];
$modelo = $_POST['modelo'];
$nroserie = $_POST['nroserie'];
$conectividade = $_POST['conectividade'];
$observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];



 $sql="INSERT INTO `rato`(`marca_rato`, `modelo`, `nroserie_rato`, `conectividade`, `observacoes`) VALUES ('$marca','$modelo','$nroserie','$conectividade','$observacoes')";


 $inserir = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);


if ($inserir) {
        //echo "salvo";
        echo "0";

    }else{
        echo "1";

    }   

?>
```

And this is my ajax request -

```
$(document).ready(function($){

 $('#ajax-form').submit(function(e){

     formData = $("#ajax-form").serialize();

     e.preventDefault();

      var dadosajax = {
     'marca' : $("#marca").val(),
     'modelo' : $("#modelo").val(),
     'nroserie' : $("#nroserie").val(),
     'conectividade' : $("#conectividade").val(),
     'observacoes' : $("#observacoes").val()   
 };

         $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: "codigo_rato.php",
          data: dadosajax,
          error: function(){
          alert('Erro !!!');
      },
          success: function(result){
            if(result == '1')
          {
              alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
          }

          else
          {
              alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
          }         

  },
  });
      $('#ajax-form')[0].reset();
return false;

 });

});
```

I want to make it so, to get a message without leaving or refreshing the page telling me if it was an error or success.

Comment: When mysqli_query() fails it returns FALSE. Don't just show "1" when it is false, show/return the error message using mysqli_error($conexao). You obviously have an error in your inserting code.

Comment: use SQL values in this format : '".$var."'

Comment: No , don’t ever put variables in the sql string. Always use prepared statements with placeholders

Comment: I would return something more meaningful than `1` or `0`.   First, for clarity, set `header("Type: text/json")` and then print `json_encode(['status'=>'success']);`. Also, mysql should be set to throw exceptions on error.

Comment: @NawedKhan i dont, it's inserting into the DB.

Comment: @TimMorton I set a try catch on the sql, and took out the if else, what should i expect in the ajax if i put `echo json_encode(['status'=>'success']);` ? It's still just returning the blank page.

Comment: Regarding try/catch: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting. Regarding `'status'=>'success'` see an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59525516 (step 5)

Comment: Being redirected to a page simply means that your form is being submitted without ajax. Please share the html of your form. Are you clicking the submit button?

Comment: @NawedKhan fixed, jquery CDN was being badly called.