# form data not resolving after click on submit button

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, form-submit, isset

I cannot get my form to work and after several hours, I must admit I'm out of ideas.
This first form on the page works correctly

```
?php
global $wpdb;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$id = isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 ;

$mesprojets = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM pp_posts WHERE post_author='".$id."'  AND post_status='publish'  AND post_type='project'  ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 8");

// Tous les posts et tous les candidats pour un client
$mescandidats = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT pp_posts.*, pp_candidates.* FROM pp_posts JOIN pp_candidates ON (pp_posts.ID = pp_candidates.project_ID)   AND pp_posts.post_author='".$id."' AND pp_posts.post_type='project'  AND pp_posts.post_status='publish'  ORDER BY pp_posts.ID DESC LIMIT 8");

echo "<table id='mesprojets' style='width:100%;' class='liste-projet'>";
foreach($mesprojets as $monprojet)
    {
        $thispostlink = get_the_permalink($monprojet->ID);
        $mescandidatspourunpost = $monprojet->ID;
        $postID = $monprojet->ID;
        $categories = get_the_category($postID);

    echo '<tr><td class="title-projet col-33" style="text-transform: uppercase;">'.$monprojet->post_title.'</td><td class="col-10">'.$categories[0]->name.'</td><td class="col-15"><a href=" '. $thispostlink . ' " class="btn-projet2">Voir le projet</a></td>
    <td class="col-15">
    <form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="candidatebutton" value="'.$mescandidatspourunpost.'" class="btn-candidat">Voir les candidats</button>
    </form></td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

This form gives me the ID which I need in the second form. The form content resolves correctly. This second form will be used to select a candidate using radio buttons and a final submit button. Ultimately, this form results will be used to update the database but for the moment I am just trying to echo some text to see if it works.

```
if (!isset($_POST['candidatebutton'])) 
  {
    global $wpdb, $postID, $thispostlink;
    echo '<div class="projectcandidatelist"></div>';
  }
else
{
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $id = isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 ;
  $useremail = $user->user_email;

  $project_candidat = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM pp_candidates WHERE project_ID ='".$_POST['candidatebutton']."' ");

if(isset($_POST['candidate_choice']))
{
  global $wpdb, $selected_candidate, $postid, $selectthiscandidate;
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Chosen");</script>';
  echo "<div class='acceptationmessage' id='acceptmission'>Merci d’avoir choisis ce candidat. Nous l’avertirons par mail de votre décision.</div>";
}

  echo '<div class="projectcandidatelist"><form action="" id="candidat_list"  name="candidat_list" method="post">
    <table id="candidate_selection_list" class="liste-candidat">';

  foreach($project_candidat as $candidat)
    {
      $selectthiscandidate = $candidat->candidate_ID;
      echo  '<tr>         
      <td class="title-candidat"><input type="radio" name="candidate_choice" value="'.$selectthiscandidate.'" > '.$candidat->candidate_displayname. '</td></tr>';
    }
  echo '</table><input type="submit" value="Je choisis cet étudiant" name="selectCandidate_btn" class="btn-candidat">';    
  echo '</form></div>';       
} 
?>
```

Neither the javascript alert nor the echo div... are showing. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is admittedly a pet peeve of mine, but if you close out of php when you’ve finished your logic and just go into html (using php for iteration and variable substitution), it makes code far easier to read and debug. Also, non-destructive requests should be GET, not POST. (research PRG pattern).  Sometimes just refactoring the code to divide logic from presentation will fix problems.  In this case, you could easily see that there is no `$_POST['candidate_choice']` being sent from the previous form.

Comment: Thanks @TimMorton for looking into this. I will try to implement what you suggest and try to see why the variable is not being sent. Could you explan or give an example of what you mean by "refactoring the code to divide logic from presentation". Thanks again

Comment: Sure, as soon as I’m able to get to it after work... :)

Comment: Seeing that you're using `global $wpdb` and `$wpdb->get_results()`, I gather that you're using WordPress?  I've rarely used WP or Joomla et al because I've seen Joomla code, and still have nightmares.  So this is the first time I've delved into WP, and although it's touted as having much better security... I'm appalled.  They don't even use prepared statements. So I'm left with a bit of a dilemma:  to show you an answer worth showing, I can't use the `$wpdb` object in good conscience.  So I'll show the example with PDO; you can use whatever you choose.

Comment: Now that I'm on my desktop instead of iphone, I also see that my comment about `$_POST['candidate_choice']` was in error.  I just couldn't see it for all the stuff around it :/  So my answer may not answer your question.  I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: I got it to work, but I'm not sure why. I will be posting the final result here soon. I guess what you were saying is more or less unclutter or limit my code here if I want help

Comment: It's more like, I have too much on my plate.  I've got an answer started, but after I realized I was wrong, there's not much point in putting out an answer that doesn't have the answer!  To explain what I meant by separating logic from presentation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59525516/2129574 (step 2 and following) for an illustration.  You should almost never need to use an `echo` or `print`, with the exception being returning json_encoded content for ajax. Congrats on getting it to work, although I know it's frustrating when you don't know *what* fixed it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is no point to work to give me an answer. As soon as I can free up some time I'm going to figure this out and post the response and look at your example. Your answer about echo and print already explains things partially. Have a great day